# Call a stack layout from another page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a **Xamarin.Forms** app using **c#**.

There is a **Button** in a **Page** and i want to add a new **Label** in **StackLayout** that is in the `Main Page` when the **Button** is clicked.

I tried to set the `FieldModifier` property of the `StackLayout` **public** in the **XAML** file, but it didn't work...

This is the layout code (i want to add the label into `MainStackLayout`) and the cs method of the **Button** click:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="white">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="MainStackLayout" x:FieldModifier="public" >
            </StackLayout>
            <Button 
                Text="Add Counter"
                BackgroundColor="darkgreen"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                CornerRadius="0"
                HeightRequest="80"
                TextColor="white"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                x:Name="AddCounter_btn"
               Clicked="AddCounter_btn_Clicked"
               >

            </Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>

private void StartCount_btn_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    Label NCounterName =new Label();
    NCounterName.Text = counter_txt.Text.ToString();
    Label NCounterNumber = new Label();
    NCounterNumber.Text = "0000";`enter code here`
}
```

Comment: Would you like that when you Click the button both NCounterName and NCounterNumber are added to the MainStackLayout?

Comment: And, did you meant AddCounter_btn_Clicked instead of StartCount_btn_Clicked?

Comment: directly modifying one view from another page is generally a pretty horrible idea.  Using MessagingCenter to do this would be a much better approach.

Comment: Does your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a button in `Page1` which is `StartCount_btn`, and when you click this button, you want to add some labels to `MainStackLayout` in Page2.

In **Page1**, send a `addLabelNotification` when you click the `StartCount_btn` button:

```
private void StartCount_btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, "addLabelNotification");
}
```

In **Page2**, Subscribe to the message and add labels when receive the message:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "addLabelNotification", (sender) =>
        {
            // Do something whenever the "addLabelNotification" message is received

            Label NCounterName = new Label();
            NCounterName.Text = "counter_txt";
            Label NCounterNumber = new Label();
            NCounterNumber.Text = "0000";

            MainStackLayout.Children.Add(NCounterName);
            MainStackLayout.Children.Add(NCounterNumber);

        });
    }
}
```

Refer: [messaging-center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code here, could not check it but it will work. Your button gives you enough information to reach any View. You just use parent-child controls.

```
private void StartCount_btn_Clicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is Button myButton)
    {
        if(myButton.Parent is StackLayout myStackLayout)
        {
            Label NCounterName =new Label();
            //set your label's text
            myStackLayout.Add.Children(NCounterName);
        }
    }
}
```